# Accessing parent directive controller from child directive in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I'm trying to access controller of a parent directive from a child directive, but no success so far.

I have this kind of parent directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mybusiness.shared')
        .directive('pkPage', pkPage);

    /* @ngInject */
    function pkPage() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            controller: 'PkpageController',
            controllerAs: 'pageCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/mybusiness/shared/pkpage/pkpage.tmpl.html'
        };
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

And this is controller of parent directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mybusiness.shared.pkpage')
        .controller('PkpageController', Controller);

    /* @ngInject */
    function Controller($filter, API, ToastService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.$filter = $filter;
        vm.API = API;
        vm.ToastService = ToastService;
        vm.clickedRow = null;

        vm.reset = function() {
            vm.pkForm.$setPristine();
            vm.pkForm.$setUntouched();
            vm.title = vm.addTitle;
        };

        vm.setContent = function(content) {
            vm.content = content;
            console.log(vm.content);
        };

        vm.save = function() {
            if (vm.clickedRow === null) {
                vm.promise = vm.API.all(vm.resource).post(vm.content);
                vm.promise.then(function () {
                    vm.ToastService.show(vm.$filter('translate')(vm.addMsg));
                    vm.refresh();
                })
            }
            else {
                vm.promise = vm.content.put();
                vm.promise.then(function () {
                    vm.ToastService.show(vm.$filter('translate')(vm.updMsg));
                    vm.refresh();
                })
            }
        };

        vm.refresh = function() {
            vm.promise = vm.API.all(vm.resource).getList();
            vm.promise.then(function (response) {
                vm.contents = response;
            })
            vm.reset();
        };

        vm.destroy = function() {
            vm.promise = vm.content.remove();
            vm.promise.then(function () {
                vm.ToastService.show(vm.$filter('translate')(vm.delMsg));
                vm.refresh();
            })
        };
    }
})();
```

Parent directive template:

```
<md-content class="padding-normal">
    <div ng-hide="vm.contents.length === 0">
        <p class="md-headline" translate>{{vm.tableTitle}}</p>
        <pk-table 
            columns = "vm.columns" 
            contents = "vm.contents"
            page-size = "10" 
            on-unselection = "vm.reset()"
            on-selection = "vm.setContent(selectedContent)"
            >
        </pk-table>
    </div>
    <p class="md-headline padding-top-10 padding-bottom-10" translate>{{vm.title = vm.selectedRow ? vm.editTitle : vm.addTitle}}</p>
    <pk-form
        input-content = "vm.content"
        on-update = "vm.save(newContent)"
        on-delete = "vm.destroy(content)"
        template-url = "ex-puoliso">
    </pk-form>
</md-content>
```

This is child directive (or part of it):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mybusiness.shared.pktable')
        .directive('pkTable', pkTable);

    /* @ngInject */
    function pkTable($filter, API) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                columns: '=',
                contents: '=',
                filters: '=',
                onSelection: '&',
                onUnselection: '&'
            },
            link: link,
            templateUrl: 'app/mybusiness/shared/pktable/pktable-directive.tmpl.html'
        };
        return directive;

        function link($scope, $element, attrs) {

    ......................

            // init custom variables
            $scope.clickedRow = null;


            $scope.onRowClick = function(content) {
                $scope.content = angular.copy(content);
                if ($scope.clickedRow === $scope.content.id) {
                    $scope.clickedRow = null;
                    $scope.content = null;
                    $scope.onUnselection();
                }
                else {
                    $scope.clickedRow = $scope.content.id;
                    $scope.onSelection({selectedContent: $scope.content});
                }
                // console.log($scope.content);
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

If I click unselected tablerow, onRowClick function runs onSelection function which is one of the child directive scope bindings and attributes. In parent directive template onSelection attribute is set to run vm.setContent() function of parent directive (pkPage) controller.

But when clicking tablerow, there is no output (vm.content or errors) in browser console. Seems to me that vm.setContent() function does not fire at all. Do you have any idea what I'm missing?

BUT:

If I move vm.setContent() function to the ui-router state controller, function start running as expected on tablerow click!

This is my ui-router state config:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mybusiness.customer-forms.permium')
        .config(moduleConfig);

    /* @ngInject */
    function moduleConfig($translatePartialLoaderProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/mybusiness/customer-forms');

        $stateProvider
        .state('triangular.customer', {
            url: '/premiums',
            views: {
                '': {
                    resolve: { /* @ngInject */
                        contents: function (API) {
                            return API.all('customer/premiums').getList();
                        }
                    },
                    template: '<pk-page></pk-page>',
                    controller: 'premiumController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

In permiumController I have all business data for respective case and that data is accessible for child directives without problems. But I don't want to move all parent directive functions to business controller because of DRY...

Hope you can have grasp of my case...

angular 1.5.5
angular-ui-router 0.3.1